# How to store integers to avoid retesting their prime status

Tags: java, performance

My program passes an integer to an `isPrime` method, which returns the boolean value `true` if the integer is prime, and `false` if it's composite.

The method is executed often, and the same integer may be passed multiple times, so it would be efficient to store the prime status of the integer somehow and have it check that when passed to avoid having to run the entire battery of divisibility tests again, especially on large integers.

How should I store the prime statuses of the integers, so that they may easily be checked? I'm thinking a Set of some sort, because they will tell you if the number you are trying to add is already inside, but I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way.

I'm working in Java.

Comment: Search for 'memoization'. In any case, the amount of benefit vs cost depends a good bit on how many times the *same* numbers are checked. For a basic Sieve of Eratosthenes an array is generally used - but for 'large numbers' such is quickly impractical.

Comment: Thanks, memoization is definitely the keyword I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `MAP<INTEGER, BOOLEAN>`, and build the map as and when you come across new integers. This way whenever you get a integer you can first check if that integer exists in the map and if so whether it has a value, if not pass it to the `isPrime` method.

I believe this approach will save you the overhead of passing the integer to the method to know if it is prime.

```
    package prime;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    public class Primes {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Map<Integer, Boolean> primes= new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
            int[] numbers = {4,7,11,15};
            primes.put(7, true);
            for(int i : numbers)
            {
                if(primes.containsKey(i) == true)
                {
                    Boolean temp = primes.get(i);
                    if(temp == null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("passing to isPrime()");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Any thing else");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("passing to isPrime()");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility:

- Move the isPrime method to a class (PrimeValidator.java for example) with a private constructor, so no one can instantiate an object from it.
- Add a private variable List _calculatedPrimes. Instantiate it.
- Create in the class the isPrime method as static and put the logic on it. This logic first check whether the number exists in the list, with the contains method. If not, use your logic.
- If necessary, create a list of _nonPrimeNumbers, in case you want to store the non prime numbers

The idea of moving the code from a method to a class is to encapsulate the internal behaviour.

Another idea:

- Create the PrimeValidator class with your original logic.
- Create a decorator class that controls the list. Make it singleton.
- The decorator first checks if it's in the list. If not, executes his internal class and records the value in the list, in case it's prime.

The benefit of the decorator is the separation of concerns, although your method is very simple... but you never know.

Here is a sample of the decorator pattern: http://www.juanpabloaraya.cl/posts/aop_decorator_interception.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Set to store all already discovered prime numbers, you can do:

```
private Set<Integer> prime = new HashSet<Integer>();

public boolean isPrime(int num){
    if(prime.contains(num)){
        return true;
    }
    //add you code that checks if prime
    //if it is prime:
    prime.add(num);
    return true;
 }
```

You can also create a set for non-prime numbers, and right away also check `if(nonPrime.contains(num)) return false;`